# Constructor on IRequestAdapter requestAdapater (cannot be null error)

Tags: c#, .net

```
IRequestAdapter requestAdapter = null!;

var graphClient = new Microsoft.Graph.Beta.GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter, https://graph.microsoft.com/beta);

var result = await graphClient.Users[{user-dummy-email@stuff.com}].Security.InformationProtection.SensitivityLabels.GetAsync();
```

I am working with Microsoft graph API to change sensitivity labels on Excel sheets.  I copied the last two lines of code from Microsoft documentation to list the sensitivity of documents in one drive for a given user.  However, when I run the entirety of my code, it throws an exception error that the variable 'requestAdapter' cannot be null.  I am trying to find documentation on this IRequestAdapter Interface that my variable is a part of but to no avail. I have tried telling the compiler that the variable is 'not' null, and I have also tried to cast to another type in the Graph library, but that does not work either.  If anyone has any information on the IRequestAdapter interface or knows how to solve this null-type problem, I would greatly appreciate it.

I tried to cast it to a different type in Graph API and tried to tell the compiler that it was not null.

I need to know how to construct the first line of code above, to construct a proper IRequestAdapter requestAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

From *Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.IRequestAdapter*:

> Service responsible for translating abstract Request Info into
> concrete native HTTP requests.

So you can implement it [github](https://github.com/microsoft/kiota-abstractions-dotnet/blob/main/src/IRequestAdapter.cs) and create your own class, or you can take *Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.**HttpClientRequestAdapter*** and implement only *IAuthenticationProvider*.

You can not solve "null type problem" just lying to compiler, that it is not null.